# Continuity of maximum modulus function $M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, entire-functions

I am looking to prove that the maximum modulus function
$$M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$$
is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ for $f$ an entire function.

My idea was to use the representation of $f$ as a power series $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{a_k}{k!} z^k$ valid on all of $\mathbb{C}$ to try to get a hold on $\left|M(r+\delta)-M(r)\right|$ but wasn't able to make much progress.

Comment: use that $M(r)$ is increasing by maximum modulus theorem so if it were discontinous, it would have a jump and that's easy to see is impossible

Comment: Why is it easy to see that a jump discontinuity is impossible?

Comment: You can also use the fact that $\log M(r)$ is a convex function of $\log (r)$, compare [Hadamard three-circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) . Convex functions are continuous.

Comment: jump impossible follows by continuity of $f$ since if say you have a jump at the right so $M(r_0)=a$ and $M(r)\ge a+\delta, r >r_0$ the continuity of $f$ shows that $M(r_0) \ge a+\delta$ too (picking a sequence $|a_k|=r_k >r, M(r_k)=|f(a_k)|, r_k \to r$ subsequence $a_k$ convergent etc); similarly you handle a left jump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Hadamard three-circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) states that $\log M(r)$ is a convex function of $\log r$, and convex functions are continuous.

But one can also prove the continuity directly, using only the fact that the derivative is continuous and therefore bounded on compact sets.

For $r \ge 0 $ set
$$
 K_r = \max \left\{ |f'(z)| : \frac 12 r \le |z| \le r + 1 \right\} \,.
$$
If $\frac 12 r \le R \le r + 1$, $|z| = R$ and $|w| = r$ with $\arg w = \arg z$ then
$$
 |f(z) - f(w)| \le K_r |z-w| = K_r |R-r| \, .
$$
First choose $z$ such that $|f(z)| = M(R)$, that gives
$$
 M(R) = |f(z)| \le |f(w)| + K_r|R-r| \le M(r) + K_r|R-r| \, .
$$
Then choose $w$ such that $|f(w)| = M(r)$, that gives
$$
 M(r) = |f(w)| \le |f(z)| + K_r|R-r| \le M(R) + K_r|R-r| \, .
$$
It follows from combining the last two inequalities that
$$
 |M(R) -M(r)| \le  K_r |R-r|
$$
for $\frac 12 r \le R \le r + 1$, and that proves the continuity of $M(\cdot)$ at $R$.

Comment: Looking back, I only follow you until the last display equation I believe. Best i can get is $||f(z)|-|f(w)|| \le |f(z)-f(w)|$. How to get $|M(R)-M(r)|$ on the LHS?

Comment: It seems you are using that $|f(w)|=M(r)$. I thought we picked $w$ such that $\operatorname{arg}w = \operatorname{arg}z$? Such a $w$ may not satisfy $|f(w)|=M(r)$.

Comment: Then how do you get your last inequality in your most recent comment? it is equivalent to $|f(w)|\ge M(r)$.

Comment: @Dispersion: There was indeed an error in the proof. I have fixed the answer, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Hmm I am still a bit confused. You first say that you first pick $w$ such that $\operatorname{arg} w = \operatorname{arg} z$, but then you choose $w$ again such that $|f(w)|= M(r)$. It's not clear to me that these two different $w$ must be the same.

Comment: @Dispersion: For the first inequality you pick $z$ with $|z|=R$ and $|f(z)| = M(R)$, and then pick $w$ with $|w|=r$ and $\arg w = \arg z$. – For the second inequality you pick $w$ with $|w|=r$ and $|f(w)| = M(r)$, and then pick $z$ with $|z|=R$ and $\arg z = \arg w$.

Comment: But the original inequality you rely on is $|f(z)-f(w)|\le K_r|z-w|$. You are "choosing" one value of $w$ for the RHS, and then a different one for the LHS. However, this is not allowed. What am I missing?

Comment: @Dispersion: Now I do not understand what you mean. We use one pair $(z, w)$ to prove the first inequality $M(R)  \le M(r) + K_r|R-r| $ and another pair $(z, w)$ to prove the inequality $M(r) \le M(R) + K_r|R-r| $. Both pairs satisfy that $|z|=R$, $|w|=r$, and $\arg z = \arg w$. For the first inequality we pick $z$ first with $|f(z)| = M(R)$ and then pick the corresponding $w$. For the second inequality we pick $w$ first with $|f(w)| = M(r)$ and then pick a corresponding $z$.

Comment: I think I understand now thanks to your latest comment. Thanks for clarifying and good answer!